# .htaccess rewrite rule needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I updated a webforum which causes the old urls to be invalid. The old structure was:

```
www.myforum.com/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=34541/
```

the new structure has to be:

```
www.myforum.com/index.php/Thread/34541
```

Can you please provide me the .htaccess-rule for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following rules to your `.htaccess` (in the root directory of your website)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.+?)&threadID=(\d+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php/%1/%2? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^page=Thread&threadID=(\d+)/?$
RewriteRule .*  index.php/Thread/%1   [L]
```

Please note that this rule redirects internally. for external redirect use `R` flag.